# Auto select input field when toggle is actioned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a search bar that only displayed when the toggle button is clicked. The code I am using to do this is:

```
$("a.search-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".search-bar").slideToggle(200);
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

Now I am trying to find a way to auto select the input[type="search"] field when this toggle is actioned. Currently the user has to click the toggle button, then click the search field which isn't very user friendly.

### Note

I am not looking for this to occur on page load, only once toggle has been activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
$('input[type="search"]').focus();
```

See the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: Perfect - thank you :)

Comment: @CharlyAnderson If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted

Comment: sure will do - as soon as it lets me. Thanks again.